# GFCI blinks red once

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci

I installed a new GFCI outlet and it seems to work; the light is generally a solid green. however it does blink red once every 30 to 90 seconds.

I found plenty of documentation around a solid red light; however what does it mean when it blinks red just once occasionally? Is it just a self test (probably not) or an actual safety hazard to be addressed?

The GFCI units I use are made my Genmax

Comment: Can you provide us with the instruction sheet for the GFCI please?

Comment: Sure thing! 
https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/95/956d4dba-a189-4a37-82b1-76eb4c2e058f.pdf

Comment: Your link points to the instruction sheet for a Leviton GFCI....

Comment: Sorry!! It's been a long day. Let's try this again:

Page 1: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PYtyxUaNj7ImsFFB6ondgTWxAUMskJuz/view?usp=sharing.         Page 2: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dEMGnqeA8DnGNcz-MDuoqEl3AfhucVON/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Was this a cheapie on Amazon?  My web searches lead to no credible manufacturer site and Amazon, Overstock, eBay and a few places like Walmart that list Amazon results.

Comment: No I bought it at the local hardware store ...